# How can I show datepicker in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I've jquery ui datepicker and I want to make my datepicker position fixed that's why I want to show datepicker in a div on responsive or mobile devices because when I scroll my page down on mobile with safari browser datepicker dissapears that's why I want to show my datepicker in a div as [booking.com datepicker](https://www.booking.com/index.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaOQBiAEBmAEuwgEKd2luZG93cyAxMMgBDNgBAegBAZICAXmoAgM;sid=afb6ab89db189a8b6ab866b9dc0e9f2f;sb_price_type=total&) (please check this lin on mobile)

```js
function datePicker() {
    var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YY",
        from = $("#checkin,.checkin").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            firstDay: 1,
            minDate: 0,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            closeText: 'Temizle',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            },
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
                    $(this).parents(".book-holiday").find("#checkout,.checkout").focus();
                }, this), 10);
                var yenitarih = new Date();
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                var checkoutStartDate = new Date(new Date(date).setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
                var checkoutEndDate = new Date(new Date(date).setDate(date.getDate() + 500000));
                $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", checkoutStartDate);
                $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker("option", "maxDate", checkoutEndDate);
            },
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
                    fromDate = from.datepicker('getDate');

                if (!fromDate || !selectedDate) {
                    return [true]
                }
                var dateClass = '';
                var dateClass = '';
                if (date > fromDate && date < selectedDate) {
                    dateClass = 'start';

                } else if (+date == +selectedDate) {
                    dateClass = 'stop';
                }
                return [true, dateClass];

            },
            beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");

            }
        });
    $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        closeText: 'Temizle',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", false);
        },

        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $(this).parents(".book-holiday").find(".popover-wrapper").addClass("open");
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
                fromDate = from.datepicker('getDate');

            if (!fromDate || !selectedDate) {
                return [true]
            }
            var dateClass = '';
            if (date > fromDate && date < selectedDate) {
                dateClass = 'start';

            } else if (+date == +selectedDate) {
                dateClass = 'stop';
            }
            return [true, dateClass];

        },
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");

        }

    });
  
}

datePicker();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

From : <input type="text" class="checkin">
To: <input type="text" class="checkout">

<div id="checkin_div"></div>
<div id="checkout_div"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/awgWLR)

Comment: You can just wrap the two `inputs` into a `div` then add a `position:fixed` using css. [Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjevXa) . Let me know if it's what you need

Comment: Replacing `#checkout` by `#checkout_div` in  `$("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker({` would be a start.

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru this is not solution I tried this but when I fixed as your think than my datepicker dissapears again that's why I need to open in a div thanks..

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks but I couldn't do events ? they open when I click and after I selected a date they must bi hide and they write to date in input is that possible ?

Comment: The behavior you describe is when it's instantiated on an input... So go for a wrapper div, like @OvidiuUnguru said. Instantiating on a div is for an always visible calendar.

Comment: yes as I said I tried but nothing change